# Pass environment variable from package.json to React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm building a React / Node / Express / Webpack (2.2.1) application and would like to know how to approach the following:

I would like an environment variable to be visible in the React client - the purpose being for certain api requests to use either the localhost or otherwise the IP address of the production server.

Is it possible to get an environment variable from running a script in package.json, to the webpack build, and then compiled and visible in the bundled javascript.

So in terminal run:

```
npm run build-dev // pass to Webpack something like APP_ENV="development"
```

or

```
npm run build-prod // pass to Webpack something like APP_ENV="production"
```

and the script definition being something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-dev": "webpack --define APP_ENV='development'"
}
```

...help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### CLI with --define option

`--define` option using `webpack.DefinePlugin` so you must pass a string value into app.

Demo

```
"scripts": {
   "build-dev": "webpack --define APP_ENV=\"'development'\""
}
```

### config webpack.config.js plugins and pass process.env into app

`APP_ENV="development" npm run build-dev` nodejs set environment variables at the head of command.you can use `webpack.EnvironmentPlugin` to expose process.env into bundle.js that I have tested.

Demo

```
"scripts": {
     "build-dev": "APP_ENV=development webpack"
 }
```

Test

```
describe('string-replace-webpack-loader', () => {
    it('environment exists', () => {
        expect(process.env.APP_ENV).toBe('dev');
    });

    it('replace environment variables', compile({
        entry: './env.js',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(Object.keys(process.env))
        ]

    }).then(({log}, files) => {
        expect(files['/bundle.js']).toMatch(/(["'])dev\1/);
    }));
});
```

Comment: ...thanks for your reply @holi-java. How does that get compiled into Webpack's bundle.js? Also, if this does work, is it possible to have the  variable in the script definition so as I'm not having to type: APP_ENV="development" npm run build-dev

Comment: `process.env.APP_ENV` could access the value.may be you need a webpack plugin to replace process.env.APP_ENV  with static string

Comment: [string-replace-loader](https://github.com/Va1/string-replace-loader) may be you need.